# Enviar una imagen en base 64 a un servidor

Tags: php, c#, imagen, servidor, base64

quisiera saber si alguien sabe como puedo enviar una imagen en base 64 a un servidor, actualmente lo hago de esta manera:

```
string imagen = "";
private static string Conversor(string Path)
        {
            byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path);
            string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
            return base64ImageRepresentation;
        }


public void subirimagen()
        {
            imagen= Conversor(textEdit2.Text);
            string nombre = textEdit1.Text;
            string foto = textEdit2.Text;
            var client = new WebClient();
            var data = client.DownloadString("http://shopticul2020abcd.dx.am/HEIDI/CONSULTAS/HEIDIPC/subirimagen.php?foto="+foto+"&nombre="+nombre+"&imagen="+imagen);
        }
```

pero me arroja el siguiente error:

`System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Long.`

Me dice que la cadena es demasiado larga pero yo no se como acortar dicha cadena.
La razón por la que envió la imagen de esta forma es por que en el servidor tengo un archivo que recibe las variables y la imagen, este archivo se encarga de transformar la cadena de base 64 a una imagen nuevamente

El lenguaje de programación que estoy usando es C# y php

Comment: Deberías usar alguno de los métodos `Upload*`, ó mejor aún usar la clase `HttpClient` y el método `PostAsync`.

Comment: Disculpa, podrías darme un ejemplo?, Es que soy nuevo en esta área y desconozco del tema, gracias